# Incorrect string value: '\xC3' for column

Tags: mysql, doctrine, collation

I can't save some data in my mysql database.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xC3' for column 'title' at row 1
```

row title use the collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

What's wrong with it? How could I save my data?

PS: I try pretty much every solution give in stackoverflow. That why I create a new thread.

Comment: Some 8-bit data is leaking into your UTF-8 world. You need to find out where that came from.

Comment: Since that's an Ã it's probably something that is UTF-8, got mangled back into ISO Latin 1, and then smashed into your column again as UTF-8, but it's not UTF-8 now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error today and the reason for it was not MySQL, but PHP.
I had a utf-8 string and cut it with substr() to 250 characters.
The problem with substr() is, that it is not utf-8 safe, as it may cut special characters "in half".

Using mb_substr() solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`C3` may indicate a utf8 character being interpreted as latin1.  Or it may indicate "double encoding".

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`

See... [*utf8*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

The solution is probably to *connect* with utf8mb4, not with the default.

What version of MySQL are you using?  What parameters does Doctrine use when connecting?

Answer (score 0):

Am getting the same error while I try to upload (<- this type [UTF8]). *'1366. Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x80' for column'*

But am changing the data type to '**mediumblob**' then its working fine.

check out the screenshot. Now the error solved

[image]